# Create a crosstable using the values of a dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

I have the following dataframe (it was organized by someone else but I would appreciate if you have any comments on how it was organized)

|  | Day | Media | Supplement | Concentration | Growth |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 | Sandy | NA (control) | C0 | 90.00 |
| 2 | 5 | Sandy | PD | C10 | 23.12 |
| 3 | 5 | Sandy | PES | C10 | 43.00 |
| 4 | 5 | Sandy | MIX | C10 | 34.00 |
| 5 | 5 | Sandy | PA | C10 | 6.00 |
| 6 | 5 | Sandy | PD | C100 | 61.46 |
| 7 | 5 | Sandy | PES | C100 | 65.00 |
| 8 | 5 | Sandy | MIX | C100 | 34.00 |
| 9 | 5 | Sandy | PA | C100 | 12.00 |
| 10 | 8 | Sandy | NA (control) | C0 | 84.00 |
| 11 | 8 | Sandy | PD | C10 | 22.00 |
| 12 | 8 | Sandy | PES | C10 | 23.00 |
| 13 | 8 | Sandy | MIX | C10 | 33.00 |
| 14 | 8 | Sandy | PA | C10 | 45.00 |
| 15 | 8 | Sandy | PD | C100 | 76.00 |
| 16 | 8 | Sandy | PES | C100 | 45.00 |
| 17 | 8 | Sandy | MIX | C100 | 55.00 |
| 18 | 8 | Sandy | PA | C100 | 23.00 |

I would like to have the following table.

[image]

I have tried multiple approaches without success. The one is closer is to select the control and treatment

PS <- First %>%
select(Supplement = "PD")

PS

Is there a way to do this from a dataframe?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way how we could do it!:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(gt)
df %>% 
  filter(Supplement == "NA (control)" |
         Supplement == "PD") %>% 
  select(-Supplement, -Media) %>% 
  pivot_wider(
    names_from = Concentration,
    values_from = Growth
  ) %>% 
  mutate(Day = paste(colnames(df[1]), Day, sep= " ")) %>% 
  rename(`Supplement PD` = Day) %>% 
  gt() %>% 
  tab_spanner(
    label=unique(df$Media),
    columns = c(C0, C10, C100)
  )
```

[image]

Comment: Could you please also tell me how could I modify the code in case I wanted a table with all "Supplements" in the same format? Thank you

Comment: Are you having this error (Error: The object to `data` is not a `gt_tbl` object.)?